# Riemann integral on a countable union of Jordan measurable sets without AC

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration, axiom-of-choice

Assume that $E, E_1,E_2, … $ are Jordan measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $E_1,…,E_n$ are disjoint, $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Riemann integrable on $E, E_1, E_2, …$.

Is it possible to prove the following equality without the axiom of choice?

$$\int_E f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int _{E_n}f$$

I know that if we assume AC, there is the Lebesgue measure and we can prove the equality using it.

Comment: Where does the axiom of choice comes into play in the proof?

Comment: @AsafKaragila countable subadditivity of Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: While proofs of countable subadditivity are commonly stated in terms of picking particular covers, it is not clear to me that this is necessary. Instead it could be phrased as "for all covers $\{I_k\}_k$ such that ...." (the existence of such covers follows from the definition of outer measure, not the AC). And even if I am mssing something, Lebesgue outer measure has nothing do with the problem itself, which is all about Riemann theory, not Lebesgue. Lebesgue outer measure is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulSinclair How do you prove the equality without using Lebesgue integral?

Comment: By using the *Riemann* Integral and *Jordan* measure, not Lebesgue measure. But before I even get into that, I am realizing I hadn't paid enough attention to the equation to be proved, and am not sure what it even means. Because of the introduction, I had been under the impression it was about summing integrals, but it isn't. The $E_n$ are sets, and therefore the $f(E_n)$ are also sets. What definition is to be used on this sum-of-sets?

Comment: @PaulSinclair That was a typo. I edited.

Comment: Okay, so note that Jordan measure is only finitely additive, and finite choice does not require AC. Prove the result first for positive $f$. First show finite additivity, then obtain countable additivity in the limit, which will be a supremum of a bounded collection. Extend to all $f$ in the same fashion that is done with Lebesgue.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand that if $f$ is positive, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{E_n}f$ converges and  is less than or equal to $\int_E f$. However, how to prove the equality?

Comment: How can it be less? That may sound like a rhetorical question, but it isn't. What would it require for the sum to be less than $\int_E f$? Is that possible when $E = \bigcup E_n$?